# Is it possible to use php's fat-free routing implementation ontop of subdomains?

Tags: php, .htaccess, fat-free-framework

Let's say we have the url:
example.com

and we have a sub-domain such as;
link1.example.com > example.com/link1

Adding the route 'GET /link1' won't work, it tries forwarding to example.com//link1 (yes, it tries double forward slashes) and it says too many redirects.

Anyone found a way around this?

**EDIT:**

If I change my .htaccess file, to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.co.uk/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

Then it redirects it to 'example.co.uk/link1' as I want, but it changes the url, is there a way to do this without it changing the url?

Comment: You should post some you what you tried so far.

Comment: I've tried modifying my htaccess file, but i but to no avail. there isn't that many things you can try and change to fix the issue, that i'm aware of. my knowledge of the .htaccess file isn't that  great.

Comment: Too many redirect usually state when you redirect from one to another and another to again one and its become infinite. if its going //link1 then try GET link1 only according to documentation its should work. or take a look over reroute $f3->reroute('@beer_list'); at http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine

Comment: My code at the moment is minimalist, it has no reroutes etc.

Comment: You cannot internally redirect to a fully qualified domain name, `http://example.co.uk/$1 [L,NC,QSA]` you would have to make it something like `/$1` alone and both the subdomain and main domain need to be in the same vhost as an alias.

Answer (score 1):

You could set other route definitions, based on the current host (and leave the htaccess as it was by default):

```
if ($f3->get('HOST')=='link1.example.com') {
  $f3->route('GET /',function(){
    echo "sub-domain page";
  });
} else {
  $f3->route('GET /',function(){
    echo "main page";
  });
}
```